# YII2 Filemanager (pdf, docx, etc)

Tags: php, file, yii2, yii-extensions, file-manager

A need this https://www.github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager to my project with yii2.

Does anyone know if there is a extension with these features?

Or how can I adapt this features to Yii2?

Thank you

Comment: English link variant: [Multi format uploader](https://pack-develop.info/en/product/6)

Answer (score 1):

I always use Yii2 Elfinder file manager. It works pretty well.

I recommend [Yii2 ElFinder](https://github.com/MihailDev/yii2-elfinder)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own backend connector / bridge.
Then extend the config to set the service urls for each action.

Create the service following this api docs https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager/blob/master/API.md